# In normal cases is there any significant advantages to creating an index that is a partial key of the begining of an existing index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If I create an index that is a partial key of the begining of a second index, how much faster (if at all) will the server be able to retrieve the results of the simpler index when the search criteria matches the simpler index?

For example if I had a non clustered index `(TransactionDate, ClientID, State)`  and my search criteria is only `TransactionDate` and `ClientID` what search performance gains would I achieve by creating a second index of `TransactionDate` and `ClientID`? The table has a pretty typical data distrubtion. There are about 12 million rows, a 100 dates with about 160,000 records per day, distributed amoung 500 clients.

Index maintenance (`inserts`, `updates`, `deletes`) and disk space usage is of no consideration. Low level detail of how sql server implements and utilizes indexes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Vague questions about optimization are not really a good fit here, as it's impossible for a single answer to be correct without access to your actual data, queries, statistics, and so forth. The best thing you can do is to test using your own data and needs and determine what works best for you. It's like asking "Which one will get to the top of the hill faster, a Ford Escort or a dump truck?" The correct answer will depend on the load, of course; an Escort will make it much faster if they're both empty, but the truck will win if they're each hauling 5 tons. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically stated you do not care about the overhead associated with maintaining multiple indexes the answer is yes.  For performance and speed a narrow index with only a single key column is better than one with multiple columns if your only searching for the first key.

If your searching for one of the 2nd, 3rd keys only.  Then putting it in it's own index is way better as it will avoid a index scan since only the first column listed in the index can be used for a direct seek.

The best practice *considering search speed only*, would be for you to break up your index into two (or even three) with each column getting it's own index when single terms are regularly searched.  The engine can still intersect multiple indexes if edge cases use more than one predicate.

*Note: If you regularly search for two predicates; then in those searches a composite index of the two is better as it doesn't have to intersect.*

In real world usage (i.e. OLTP vs OLAP or where disk space considerations may dictate otherwise) the best approach may vary - but again, you said you didn't care about that.

Be advised, your real world perception of any performance gains / speed gains may be absolutely in-perceptible; but in some circumstances any little bit helps.  [Take a glance at this Microsoft's SQL Index Performance Checklist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647681.aspx).

---

**Additional update:**

This is a very good article on the subject by Brad McGehee

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/composite-indexes/

Comment: The engine would intersect multiple indexes, I'm unfamiliar with that concept how does index intersection work?

Comment: In short the query optimizer will create a join between the two search predicates of the two indexes (though that may be oversimplifying it a bit).  Here's a good article on the actual workings:  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/

Comment: I updated with another article on the topic that has good info

Comment: Thanks for the simple-talk article RThomas. The diagram on index structures gives me a little more insight. Using the shorter search predicate (TransactionDate and Client), on the longer index (TransactionDate,Client,State), it is conceivable that SQL server would use the shorter search predicate to find the appropriate node on the Client level and then navigate to the two extremes of that branch to retreive the range, and then traverse the links of the leaf nodes retreive the records.

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I had a non clustered index (TransactionDate, ClientID, State) and my search criteria is only TransactionDate and ClientID what search performance gains would I achieve by creating a second index of TransactionDate and ClientID?

Generally none.

The index `(TransactionDate, ClientID)` will be slightly narrower (since it doesn't need to store `State`), but it will still have the same number of leafs (and pointers to table rows). Hence, while it *will* cluster the nodes more tightly, the advantage is likely to be slim.

The overhead of maintaining an extra index will almost certainly outweigh this benefit. And by maintaining I don't mean just modifying, I also mean caching, so you might see better practical search performance from single index even though the additional index might be theoretically better.

BTW, if your table happens to be clustered, this would make the secondary indexes even more expensive and less desirable.

I you are not already familiar with the topic, I warmly recommend taking a look at the [Anatomy of an SQL Index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy). In any case, I recommend **measuring** on realistic amounts of data before coming to your own conclusions.

Comment: So SQL Server will use the longer indexes almost as efficiently as the shorter index to return the shorter search predicate?

Comment: @Walter Yup, almost as efficiently. You only need to ensure that WHERE matches the **leading edge** of an index, the "remainder" of the index doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Walter BTW, `SELECT State FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE (TransactionDate BETWEEN @min_td AND @max_td) AND ClientID = @CID` will work far more efficiently off the **wider** index. This is called "covering" or ["index-only scan"](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index). Even a simple equi-search: `SELECT State FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE TransactionDate = @td AND ClientID = @CID` should be slightly faster.